# :error: expected expression before 'struct'

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, sizeof

I'm doing a lab on Linked Lists in C, and I'm getting an error that I can't seem to shake. The lab is due in 2 hours so any help would be amazing!

This is what I have for code:

```
void insert(int x, struct Node **pL)
{
    if(*pL == NULL){
        *pL = malloc(sizeOf(struct Node *pL)); // error here
        *pL->value = x; // error #2
        *pL->next = NULL;
    }else if(*pL != NULL){
        insert(x, &((*pL)->next));
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?!!

That covered that error, but now I'm getting an error that says, "error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union.

FINISHED! THANK YOU FOR ALL OF THE HELP!

Comment: *"lab is due in 2 hours"*  I would have tried to learn how to use `sizeof` prior to two hours before an assignment is due.

Comment: your sizeOf should be sizeof and you want to malloc (sizeof (struct Node)); rather than the size of a pointer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is rarely suitable for last-minute help. Try to ask about your problems before they become emergencies.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Comment: ..and if you must post linked-list questions, you should port all the typedefs etc. that we might need to understand your data.   IMHO, I think you're doomed.  2 hours to go and you have not got it to compile yet:(   How long do you think testing and debugging will take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void insert(int x, struct Node **pL)
{
```

So far this tells you you get a pointer to a pointer, a clear sign your function should modify `*pL` if necessary.

```
    if(*pL == NULL){
        *pL = malloc(sizeOf(struct Node *pL)); // error here
```

and you try here, but the syntax is wrong. First it's `sizeof`, not `sizeOf`. C is case sensitive. Then the `sizeof` operator takes **either** a type **or** an expression to determine its storage size. So you can either write `sizeof(struct Node)` or `sizeof(**pL)`. Note the *double* asterisk here, what you want is the storage size of a `struct Node` and with only one asterisk, your expression would be of type `struct Node *` (a *pointer* to a `struct Node`).

```
        *pL->value = x; // error #2
```

This is just wrong because `->` has higher precedence than `*`, so it means `*(pL->value) = x;`. **Not** what you want, you want `(*pL)->value = x;`.

```
        *pL->next = NULL;
    }else if(*pL != NULL){
```

This line doesn't make much sense (although not exactly an error). `*pL` can either be `NULL` or **not** be `NULL`. A plain `else` will do here.

```
        insert(x, &((*pL)->next));
    }
}
```

I really wonder why you get the parenthesis correct in *this* last line and still don't see the error some lines above yourself? Just adding here: being precise and conscientious is crucial in programming (and even more so in a language like C).

All in all, the code should probably look like this:

```
void insert(int x, struct Node **pL)
{
    if(*pL == NULL) {
        *pL = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        (*pL)->value = x;
        (*pL)->next = NULL;
    } else {
        insert(x, &((*pL)->next));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so helpful

Comment: @lovethehelp please accept what you consider to be the best answer if it has resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
*pL = malloc(sizeof(*pL));
```

The operator is `sizeof`, not `sizeOf`.

Also, `struct Node *pL` is a *declaration*, and it doesn't make sense to pass this to `sizeof`.  `sizeof` expects either a type, or a variable.

Comment: That covered that error, but now I'm getting an error that says, "error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union.

Comment: Methinks that you don't really have any idea how pointers work, and are trying to just throw code together to get your lab completed. Sorry, we can't teach you C programming. And not in 2 hours.

Comment: Change to pL->value rather than *pL->value

Comment: I've been watching pointer videos all week, and reading about them as well. I'll admit I am having a hard understanding, but not from lack of trying. I've never written C before, and I'm trying to learn the syntax as I go. Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: Thank you Colin_s for your help. That's not working either though.

Comment: I'm thinking about making another pointer, and pointing the pointer to the pointer. Don't know if that will work, but I'm going to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Your second error is due to operator precedence.

`->` has higher precedence than `*`. So `*pL->value` is evaluated as `*(pL->value)` instead of `(*pL)->value`

Comment: Thank you! It fixed the error! I really appreciate the help